# How can I add new rows, then cut/paste data to them?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a large spreadsheet. It is a list of workers names and columns numbered 1 to 19. Each of these numbers represents a certain task.

Where a person has worked on more than one task I would like to insert a row underneath the workers name for each seperate task they worked on, then move the data (hours spent) for each task onto these newly created seperate rows.

Some may have worked on two tasks, some on more. However many tasks they have worked on I would like to automatically add enough rows to accommodate each task on a separate row then move the data off the original row onto these newly created rows.

The idea being that once I have this format I can use a vlookup to populate what task they were working on from another dataset into a separate column.

screenshot of the spreadsheet, with unnecessary columns hidden
[image: Here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet, with unnecessary columns hidden]

I have highlighted a couple of examples of where a worker has worked on more than one task on a given day.

My formula knowledge in Excel is ok but my knowledge on macro creation is lacking.

Comment: Did you already try writing a macro? Did you look at guides on how to write them? Stackoverflow is usually not for asking people to write code for you, but to get some help on fixing issues with your code, which in this case there is none from what I understand. I'd recommend starting to write some code, and if you're stuck or have some trouble understanding how to do it, to ask another question with your code so that we can help you out :)

Comment: Consolation: Having several rows for the same item often offers itself as a solution. But such solutions invariably get chucked out within a year, often before they are fully implemented. They just add complication to an already complicated task and therefore become sources of error. The next approach is more reasonable: split the tasks of data capture and data presentation. Neither ideal format will look remotely like your spreadsheet. If you follow that advice you will create a durable solution which it is fun to work on and work with.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I wasn't aware of this. I haven't tried VBA in a long time, I just remember sucking at it. Was hoping a charitable soul might help me. I don't really have time to learn it as the work is time sensitive. Perhaps ill google a service who i can pay to write the above for me.

Comment: @Variatus The data capture and presentation are different. the spreadsheet links the data from multiple other sheets which catalogue the mens working habits daily, this is collated into one sheet here. I am trying to make this data searchable. The original data is from a subcontractor for a job that finished a year ago, it is for defence of a claim from them. If I had the luxury of setting it up in a better form from the outset I would, but thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inserting new rows into an existing sheet, create a new blank sheet called for example "NEWDATA". Then by scanning the rows and the hours columns N to AF on the original "DATA" sheet create a new row on NEWDATA if the hours > 0. Copy row to NEWDATA and delete the hours column data. Then on the new row insert back the one column of hours you are scanning. Here is some example code to further illustrate the idea. It also on another new sheet called "NORMALISED" creates rows with the 3 columns "Name","Task" and "Hours".

```
Option Explicit
Sub normalize()

    Const COL_NAME As String = "K"
    Const HRS_START As String = "N"
    Const HRS_END As String = "AF"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' sheet with source data
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("DATA")

    ' new sheet
    Dim wsNEW As Worksheet
    Set wsNEW = wb.Sheets("NEWDATA")
    ws.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy wsNEW.Cells(1, 1) ' copy header

    ' sheet to put normaized data
    Dim wsNormal As Worksheet
    Set wsNormal = wb.Sheets("NORMALIZED")
    wsNormal.Cells.Clear
    wsNormal.Range("A1:C1") = Array("Name", "Task", "Hours")

    ' create array of tasks from sheet header
    Dim arTasks As Variant
    arTasks = ws.Range(HRS_START & "1:" & HRS_END & "1").Value
    'Debug.Print "UBound(rngTask) = " & UBound(rngTasks, 2)

    Dim iLastRow As Long
    iLastRow = ws.Range(COL_NAME & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Debug.Print "Last row = " & iLastRow

    ' declare variables
    Dim iRow As Long, iNewRow As Long, iCol As Integer, iColTask0 As Integer, cell As Range
    Dim sName As String, sTask As String, sngHrs As Single, count As Long
    iColTask0 = ws.Range(HRS_START & "1").Column - 1
    iNewRow = 1
    'Debug.Print "iColTask0", iColTask0

    ' scan the data
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
        sName = ws.Range(COL_NAME & iRow).Value
        For iCol = 1 To UBound(arTasks, 2)
            sngHrs = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol + iColTask0)
            sTask = arTasks(1, iCol)
            If sngHrs <> 0 Then
                iNewRow = iNewRow + 1

                ' 3 columns of normalised data
                With wsNormal.Cells(iNewRow, 1)
                   .Offset(0, 0) = sName
                   .Offset(0, 1) = sTask
                   .Offset(0, 2) = sngHrs
                End With

                ' copy row
                ws.Range("A" & iRow & ":" & HRS_END & iRow).Copy wsNEW.Range("A" & iNewRow)
                ' blank hours
                wsNEW.Range(HRS_START & iNewRow & ":" & HRS_END & iNewRow).Value = ""
                ' insert hours for task
                wsNEW.Cells(iNewRow, iCol + iColTask0) = sngHrs

               'Debug.Print iRow, sName, sTask, sngHrs
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' result
    Dim msg As String
    msg = iLastRow - 1 & " rows scanned on " & ws.NAME & vbCrLf & _
    iNewRow - 1 & " rows created on " & wsNEW.NAME
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much! The newdata set doesn't have the time out and the total hours in at the end, but nothing vlookup on the original dataset can fill that in no problem.